# Jboss Eclipse Debugging

Tags: java, jboss5.x

I deployed a war inside `jboss5.1.0-GA`. And if I started jboss with eclipse, I'm not able to debug the java files inside eclipse.

Able to debug jsp scriptlets.
    Event tried with remote debugging.
    Set the java opt properly. (`set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4142,server=y,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTS%`)

Is there any problem in Jboss 5.1.0 ?

Comment: None that I am aware of, since I used to debug JBoss 5.1.0-GA. Could you maybe be more specific about the problem you are encoutering? There is not much of question in here, or at least none with an interesting answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) add

```
set JAVA_OPTS= -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTS%
```

ou

```
JAVA_OPTS= "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n $JAVA_OPTS"
```

to script that starts JBoss (run.sh or run.bat)

2) Start JBoss. Wait

3) Attach debuger to port 4142.

Comment: Issue solved... The problem is am creating the war using ant script. In the script in the compile target i forgot to mention debug="true". Because of the mistake am not able to debug... Thanks for u r reply...